# Android (2.2.1) Bluetooth: HTC Wildfire: Connecting to PC from Android: Have to change UUID every time?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth server listening for incoming connection, on the Laptop. 
Android is a client and wants to connect to PC.

What's wrong?
I can connect first time and send data to PC. When I turn off the Android Activity and start it again, connect function passes, but PC does not register new connection. When I try sending the data, android system logs following:

**05-16 13:11:17.091: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(102): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/30064/hci0/dev_50_63_13_CB_52_96**

What works?
If I change server's UUID, on the server and on the client, it will work again first time I try connection. Consequent tries do not work.

Server code:

```
    /** Waiting for connection from devices */
private void waitForConnection() {
    // retrieve the local Bluetooth device object
    LocalDevice local = null;

    StreamConnectionNotifier notifier;
    StreamConnection connection = null;

    // setup the server to listen for connection
    try {
        local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);

        UUID uuid = new UUID("af29e59088cc11e1b0c40800200c9a56", false);
        System.out.println(uuid.toString());

        String url = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid.toString() + ";name=ThinBTClient";                     
        notifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open(url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    // waiting for connection
    while(true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Wait Thread: Waiting for connection...");
            connection = notifier.acceptAndOpen();        

            System.out.println("Got connection");               
            Thread processThread = new Thread(new ProcessConnectionThread(connection));
            processThread.start();              
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    UUID SPP_UUID = UUID.fromString("af29e590-88cc-11e1-b0c4-0800200c9a56");

    try {
        btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        btSocket.connect();
        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I tested the same code on another laptop, Toshiba/Win7 and code works without a problem. So I suspect this is something with drivers. I will try updating.